# Bootstrap panel header and body shorter than panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap panels for the first time, and my panel header and panel body are shorter than my panel which looks a bit strange. I'm a bit stuck as to what's actually happening as the bootstrap styling is being called.

[image]

[image]

Code below:

```
<div class="software well row hidden">

        <div class="info">
            <div class="panel panel-success">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h3>This INSERT NAME is available to download!</h3></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Or if you've tried that and experienced issues then please fill out the additional info box below and a member of the service desk will be in touch.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap is this? v3?

Comment: @chade yes it is :)

Comment: And which specific version? Like 3.3.7 thich is the latest

Comment: Yes it's version 3.3.7

Comment: Hmm. I [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/pbdevch/6t9afwdu/) the error in a JSFiddle. Look if your CSS is overwritten by some theme or by your own styles.

Comment: @chade that was it thanks - it was a css style that was overwriting my panel and not my panel-heading as I was expecting!

Comment: Ok I'll write a community-wiki answers so other visitors won't have to read all trough the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Comments:

> Hmm. I [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/pbdevch/6t9afwdu/) the error in a JSFiddle. Look if your CSS is overwritten by some theme or by your own styles.

Response:

> @chade that was it thanks - it was a css style that was overwriting my panel and not my panel-heading as I was expecting!

[I'm answering this so other users with the same problem can easily determine the answer that was provided.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat)